# Combining multiple excel formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have three different formulas that I would like to combine into one formula;

In cell I2 : `=IF(ISNA(MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2,D2),INTRAFREQNCELL!E:E,0)),"NO","YES")`

In cell J2 : `=IF(ISNA(MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2,D2),INTERFREQNCELL!E:E,0)),"NO","YES")`

In cell K2 : `=IF(I2=J2,"NO","YES")`

The formula in cell `I2` and cell `J2` look for matches in two separate sheets and return a `YES` if there is a match, or `NO` if there is no match.

The formula in cell `K2` returns a `YES` if cell `I2` and cell `J2` match.

What I want to do is to get rid of columns `I` and `J` by combining the formula in all three cells.

I've tried using the `INDEX` function to do this but it didn't work. Is this possible?

Comment: Formula in Cell `I2 ` &  `J2` are identical therefore use any one and after that Formula in Cell `K2` is not required !!

Comment: Y don't you share some sample data with us and so that we just fix the issue in better way.

Comment: @RajeshS they are looking at different sheets. Cell `I2` is looking at `INTRA`freqncell and cell `J2` is looking at `INTER`freqncell

Comment: @fixer1234 it's not a typo, I2 is looking at `INTRA`freqncell and cell `J2` is looking at `INTER`freqncell

Comment: ,, yeah in first look both sheet names  looks similar !! ☺

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't enough information to see if your formulas work properly, so I'll just address combining them.

In general, if a formula contains a reference to the result in another cell, you can usually just replace the reference with the formula (excluding the initial `=`) in the referenced cell, as long as it's not an array formula (displayed with curly braces around it).

Doing that with K2 would yield:

```
=IF(IF(ISNA(MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2,D2),INTRAFREQNCELL!E:E,0)),"NO","YES")=IF(ISNA(MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2,D2),INTERFREQNCELL!E:E,0)),"NO","YES"),"NO","YES")
```

However, you can do better than that with your formulas because each one tests for a True/False condition, and then just displays the result as Yes/No, and you're using the same logical direction for each one.  So you can simplify what's copied from I2 and J2 to just compare the True/False result:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2,D2),INTRAFREQNCELL!E:E,0))=ISNA(MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2,D2),INTERFREQNCELL!E:E,0)),"NO","YES")
```

Since your output is just No/Yes, you could simplify it even more if True/False would suffice rather than Yes/No.  You can just use the logical result of the comparison.

It appears your No and Yes may be reversed, showing "No" if I2 and J2 match and "Yes" if they don't).  So just test for `=` or `<>`, depending on which you want to show as "True":

```
=ISNA(MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2,D2),INTRAFREQNCELL!E:E,0))=ISNA(MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2,D2),INTERFREQNCELL!E:E,0))
```

or

```
=ISNA(MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2,D2),INTRAFREQNCELL!E:E,0))<>ISNA(MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2,D2),INTERFREQNCELL!E:E,0))
```

Comment: #Fix1234,, it's working you get 10 ☺